# Change shortcut of subscript from 'ctrl+_' into 'ctrl+l' failed?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, shortcut

I want to change the shortcut of subscript from `ctrl+_` into `ctrl+l`. I find the KeyEventTranslations.tr file, successfully change superscript from `ctrl+6` into `ctrl+h`. But when I do the same thing to subscript, i.e., comment the original code, change it into mine `ctrl+l` by

```
Item[KeyEvent["l", Modifiers ->{Control}],  "Subscript"]
```

but when I reopen Mathematica, the subscript does not work. Why didn't it work?

I tried to change the binding, find that `ctrl+q` works well, it seems that `ctrl+l` has been used by something else, how can I change `ctrl+l` to what I want it to?

Comment: Possibly better to ask this at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First search the [shortcuts list of mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html), find that its original function is `Input from Above`. So we need to comment the code below from `MenuSetup.tr` file

```
MenuItem["&Input from Above", FrontEnd`DuplicatePreviousInput[After], MenuKey["l", Modifiers->{"Control"}]]
```